# "An invalid character was found in text content. ;" when executing SSIS from SQL server 2016

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am executing the package from my machine without any issues. But when I deploy it on the server I am getting the following error in the very beginning of the execution:

> "An invalid character was found in text content. ;   at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsContainer.Execute(Connections
> connections, Variables variables, IDTSEvents100 events, IDTSLogging100
> log, Object transaction)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISServerExecutionEvents.StartPackage()"

Comment: Are you working with XML files, by chance? `An invalid character was found in text content` often indicates that a .NET process opened an XML file with a particular encoding (e.g. `UTF8Encoding`) but the document has a different encoding or declares a different encoding in its DTD, e.g.: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>`.

Comment: I don't have any xml jobs inside the package.

Comment: Is the ssis project set to target SQL 2016?  Is the target server definitely 2016?  Are the packages begin deployed to the file system or the catalog?  How are they being executed?  SQL Agent?

Comment: Thank you guys! It appeared that the guys who deployed the ENV Variable had some typo errors with characters not supported. So when it started parsing the ENV variable it was throwing errors. Thank you once again!